# Return a JSONArray as an HTTP Entity

Tags: java, javascript, json, http, rest

**Summary**: I want to return a JSONArray via an HTTP response. How do I do that?

I am working on a problem where I was previously returning a JSON object, which was being converted to JSONEntity and then a HTTPEntity using a utility that I have. Now I need to return an JSONArray, but I don't know how to have my REST service return the array. If someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

**A little background:** 
I was previously using a DOJO ItemWriteStore to build a tree. Now I am switching to a JSONRestStore to enable my tree to have lazy loading. The problem came up because most stores in Dojo take JSONObjects, but the JSONRestStore, which supports lazy loading, needs a JSONArray.

Aslo, I am using the org.apache.http package for my HTTP repsonse

Comment: A json encoded object is a string so whats the problem?

Comment: Some good java examples. http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) library to encode it into a JSONArray object.